# Button That When Clicked Will Display Hidden Column in HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quick question. I have a button defined as:

```
<input type='button' id='button' value='Development View' >
```

A div tag that encloses the following information:

```
echo "<div id = 'content' style='display:none'>";
    echo "<th>Development Status</th>";
echo "</div>";
```

Some JavaScript that runs whenever the button is clicked:

```
var button = document.getElementById('button'); // Assumes element with id='button'

button.onclick = function() {
     var div = document.getElementById('content');
     if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
         div.style.display = 'none';
     }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
};
```

My ultimate goal is to toggle the visibility of a column in a dynamic HTML table but I can't even get this simple header tag toggling. I do not get an error message but the button does nothing it seems. I am echoing out the HTML because this is a PHP script.

Comment: Works fine for me http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWGKqb

Comment: I don't think you can wrap a table row inside of a div.  You can put a div inside a table column.  Just not outside.  If it absolutely NEEDS to be a table, you should create a whole new tableset, even if it's just one row, and wrap that in a div.

Comment: I notice there's a space before and after the "=" in your div tag. See if it helps to use '<div id="content" style="display: none">' instead.

Comment: I might just have to get this button pointing to another page with the column visible...

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your javascript in a window.onload event

```
window.onload = function () {

  var button = document.getElementById('button'); // Assumes element with id='button'

  button.onclick = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('content');
    if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
      div.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
      div.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: does it behave the same way as before, or do you get an error message  - there was a typo in the code I posted, so that might have been in - just fixed it :)

Comment: If you console.log the button or div variables, is it loading the right elements or are they null?

Comment: When i do console.log(button) it loads the correct element. When i do console.log(content) it loads "[div#content, th#content, content: div#content]". So i do not think they are null