# Appending Html Classes To Elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I asked a question yesterday ([Button That When Clicked Will Display Hidden Column in HTML Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756143/button-that-when-clicked-will-display-hidden-column-in-html-table)). The Name is self-explanatory however, after hours of trying new things and failing I decided to research a different approach. Here is what came up with:

- A button that when clicked will append a new class to an element
- By doing this, we will toggle a column's visibility by using the 'display' function in css

I have the following HTML element:

```
echo "<td class =\"development\" id = 'tag$i'>test1</th>";
echo "<td class =\"development\" id = 'tag$i'>test2</th>";
echo "<td class =\"development\" id = 'tag$i'>test3</th>";
```

$i is the row number so picture each of these `<td>` being wrapped inside a forloop to create a column.

With Css:

```
.development{
    text-align:center;
    padding-left:10px;
    display:block;
}

.hide{
    display:none;
}
```

So this is where I will need your help. I propose a button that when clicked will run a JavaScript function that can append the '.hide' class to the td tags.

```
<button onclick="addCss()">Click me</button>
```

I am not sure how to write the JavaScript and if I need to pass any parameters such as the id's for the `<td>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('yourId').className += ' ClassName'

//To select elements by class name.
 document.getElementsByClassName('yourId')
```

Note: the space after the first ' for the appended class name is important.

Why? : If you have the class name "class1" and append "class2" - It will result in "class1class2"

By adding the space, it will result in "class1 class2" and be recognized as two separate classes.

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('yourId').className += ' ClassName';">Click me</button>
```

If you want to make a better solution.

```
<script>

function addCss(element) {   
document.getElementById(element).className += ' ClassName'; 
}

</script>
```

Then just call the function like you originally had. You could even add a parameter for the class name itself.

Comment: Looks like this method only allows me to append the hide class to only one '<td>' tag

Comment: @user3272303 Does each <td> have the same id? I am assuming id = 'tag$i' is incrementing each time, thus applying different IDs.

Comment: Yes different id's. I don't think elements can have same id's, it won't give out an error but it wouldn't work either.

Comment: Elements can have the same id's. It would work. Should elements have the same id though? No, they should be unique. I have updated my code to use .getElementsByClassName rather than ID.

Comment: Weird because when I try using the same id's only the first one gets picked up...

Comment: You may be right. You could use a container div if you were just trying to apply a class to everything. For example, apply a hide class to the container/parent div to hide all of them.

Answer (score 0):

to override a class `document.getElementById("id").className = "newclass";`
to add a new class `document.getElementById("id").className += " anotherclass";`

```js
function addCss(){
document.getElementById("b").className = "hide"; 
}

function newCss(){
document.getElementById("b").className = "show"; 
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 3em;
  background: honeydew;
}

.hide {
  display: none;  
}

.show {
  display: table-cell;  
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td id=a style="background:skyblue">A</td>
<td id=b style="background:yellowgreen">B</td>
<td id=c style="background:gold">C</td> 
<td id=d style="background:orangered">D</td>
</tr>
</table>

<button onclick="addCss()">hide B cell</button>
<button onclick="newCss()">show B cell</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery, you can add this in the addCss function:

```
$('td').addClass('hide');
```

Comment: Please explain the down vote, as requested in the question, this will hide the td tags.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but it's probably because (a) the OP didn't specify jQuery; and (b) including jQuery for such a trivial task is not good practice